# javafx - Setting the background of a png image

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, pane, vbox

I have an `ImageView` that is made of a png image (transparent background). I want to change the color of the image continuously. I can change the color using `JFXFillTransition` method in the jfoenix library. The constructor of that method requires `javafx.scene.layout.Region`, so it can't be applied on `javafx.scene.Image.ImageView` directly. I am using a `VBox` and adding the `ImageView` in that `VBox`. Obviously the `VBox`'s width doesn't wrap the content (here `ImageView`) by default. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504568/wrap-content-in-javafx) gives a solution of wrapping content. But group can't be used as an argument of `JFXFillTransition` here. As a result of this, if I run the code the color of the `VBox` changes but that is not confined to the `ImageView` (as the `VBox` is larger than the image). So, how can I shrink the size of the `VBox` so that it wraps the image only (any other pane suitable for this is also ok)?

Code Snippet:

```
VBox openingImageBox = new VBox();
    openingImageBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    openingImageBox.getChildren().add(openingImageView);
    borderPane.setTop(openingImageBox);


    //Transition On ImageView
    JFXFillTransition transition1 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.VIOLET,Color.INDIGO);
    JFXFillTransition transition2 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.INDIGO,Color.BLUE);
    JFXFillTransition transition3 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN);
    JFXFillTransition transition4 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.GREEN,Color.YELLOW);
    JFXFillTransition transition5 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.YELLOW,Color.ORANGE);
    JFXFillTransition transition6 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.ORANGE,Color.RED);
    JFXFillTransition transition7 = new JFXFillTransition(Duration.millis(1000),openingImageBox,Color.RED,Color.VIOLET);
    transition1.play();
    transition1.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition2.play();
    });
    transition2.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition3.play();
    });
    transition3.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition4.play();
    });
    transition4.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition5.play();
    });
    transition5.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition6.play();
    });

    transition6.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition7.play();
    });
    transition7.setOnFinished(e->
    {
        transition1.play();
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the `VBox` growing larger than the `ImageView`? You should be able to configure the layout of the `VBox` within its parent so that won't happen (though you didn't post the code that showed what that parent was, so it's not really possible to answer the question).

Comment: The parent of the VBox is BorderPane . I haven't modified anything in the borderPane . From the fourth line of my code you will see that the VBox is placed at the Top position of the BorderPane

Comment: So just wrap the `VBox` in another pane that won't force it to grow? E.g. `VBox` in a `Pane` or `Group` in the `BorderPane`?

Comment: Not only VBox any other pane which can  help in doing this will also work.Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: As I just said, put the `VBox` in a `Group` and put the `Group` in the `BorderPane`

Comment: Thanks,it is working